# Comparing two GUID's in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, guid

I am working on a C program from Visual Studio 2010. I need to create GUID's and then compare.

I am including "#include guiddef.h" in my progarm.

Following is the code snippet but I keep on getting errors when I compile my code.

```
//mainGUID is assign value in the program
GUID mainGUID;

//Function call which compares passed GUID with the mainGUID
int CheckGUID(GUID guid)
{
  if(IsEqualGUID(guid,mainGUID))
   return 1;
  else
   return 0;
}
```

I get following error

```
Error   3   error C2172: 'memcmp' : actual parameter is not a pointer : parameter 1

Error   3   error C2172: 'memcmp' : actual parameter is not a pointer : parameter 2
```

Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

The function [`IsEqualGUID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680575) takes `REFGUID` parameters:

```
BOOL IsEqualGUID(
  _In_  REFGUID rguid1,
  _In_  REFGUID rguid2
);
```

And a `REFGUID` is `typedef GUID* REFGUID`. So you might get away with:

```
IsEqualGUID(&guid, &mainGUID)
            ^      ^
```

Caveat lector: I don't really have any experience with `IsEqualGUID`, this is all from MSDN (and the error message is also points towards this, yes).

Comment: Well "&" works provided the project properties are set to Compile As "Default" and not a "Comple as C Code (/TC)" . The project compiles now well I'll make sure it works too.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `IsEqualGUID` calls `memcmp` under the hood, and `memcmp` expects pointers as its parameters.